# Calculating Birthday in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my sheet I have records for birthday column like 21/09/1976 or 21/3/2001 in dd/mm/yyyy format. I need to calculate today's birthday names from the sheet. I have used

```
var bdate= sheet.getRange(5, 3).getValue(); 
sheet.getRange(5, 8).setValue(bdate.getDay());
```

But it is giving me error .getDay() is not a function. How to convert my data into date format. I have tried following

```
var bdate= new Date(sheet.getRange(5, 3).getValue());
sheet.getRange(5, 8).setValue(bdate.getDay());
```

but it did not return me the perfect output. Can we simply add formula in the sheet for the same rather than using google script ?

Comment: You should fix it in your sheet. If a proper date is entered in A2,`=ISDATE(A2)` should return true

Comment: Giving me error ISDATE is not defined for google sheets. can we convert it to date and use it?

Comment: Supported and defined: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert date format from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "mm/dd/yyyy".
You can try this.

```
  var DateString="21/03/2020"
  DateString=DateString.split("/")
  var bdate=new Date(DateString[1]+"/"+DateString[0]+"/"+DateString[2])
  var temp=bdate.getDay()
```

Comment: Can we simply add formula in the sheet for the same? rather than using google script